# CanCan/Rolify gives incorrect Ability results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, rolify

Given the following Ability;

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
   def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest
    if user.has_role? :project_lead
      can :read, Project, :id => Project.with_role(:project_lead, user).pluck(:id)
    end
  end
end
```

Why do I get *false* for this user's ability to :read the project?

```
>>u=User.find_by_login("test")
>>p=Project.find(1)
>>u.add_role :project_lead, p
>>u.roles
[#<Role id: 10035, name: "project_lead", resource_id: 1, resource_type: "Project", created_at: "2013-11-28 09:18:58", updated_at: "2013-11-28 09:18:58">]

>>a=Ability.new(u)
>>a.can? :read, p
false
```

I've noticed that when initialising the Ability, the WHERE clause ends with:

```
AND (((roles.name = 'project_lead') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
```

Shouldn't it read
    'AND (((roles.name = 'project_lead') AND (roles.resource_type =**'Project'**) AND (roles.resource_id = **1**)))'
?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? CanCan has flaky (at best) support for Rails 4.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.13. I think I should be okay with this version.

Comment: move on to gem pundit ... better maintenance , easy to switch on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one by correctly configuring the relationship between user and role.
Only took me 4 months.

Comment: Can you please give me more details about your solution. I'm with the same problem. Apparently my relationship between user and role are ok, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry but I don't recall. I should have put more details here. At the time this was clear enough.